# How can I replace elements of a list with values of corresponding indices of another list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have these two lists:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
L2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 12]'
```

What I want to say is this:

If an element in L2 is equal to 12, replace the value of the corresponding element in L1 with 12.

So if I then print L1, I get

```
1, 12, 3, 4, 12
```

I am having much difficulty figuring this out and I've searched for it many times in the past few days as well. Even if the answer's out there I'd appreciate a solution to this specific problem because I'm new to python and might have a difficult time adapting one person's code to my own needs. Many thanks.

Comment: Look into the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function

Comment: You could also try `zip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> L2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 12]
>>> [12 if y==12 else x for x,y in zip(L1, L2)]
[1, 12, 3, 4, 12]
```

Comment: Found this to be even more versatile. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the indices *and* values of a list by using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, element in enumerate(L2):
    # local variable 'i' contains the index
    # local variable 'element' contains the value
```

You can check the value of an element by using a [comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

```
if element == 12:
    # do something
```

You can [set the item](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) at index `i` in a list to a `new_value` with this syntax:

```
L1[i] = new_value
```

This should give you all the pieces you need to write a working loop, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @TigerhawkT3

```
    #modify existing list
    x = [y if y == 12 else x for x,y in zip(x,y)]

    ##create newlist,instead of changing existing one
    newx=[]
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        if j==12:
            newx.append(12)
        else:
            newx.append(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 for i, item  in enumerate(sourcelist):
            if i>=len(destlist):
                      break
            elif item==value:
                      destlist[i]=item
```

Or if you want to feel cool.

```
 tmp = map(lambda x,y: x if x==value else y, sourcelist, destlist)[0,min(len(source list), len(destlist))]
 sourcelist = tmp
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot, I'll look into the enumerate function

Comment: You have a typo in enumerate